# Rspec validation test for DB insert with Load Balancer

Tags: rspec, load-balancing

I'm trying to create a rspec test which covers the following scenario.
There is a Model with unique index of a column. In a real world environment I have a load balancer and want to simulate the creating behavior, so when two duplicates records are inserted the DB validation is triggered. Is it a good approach to use Thread class to bypass the rails default **validates :username, :uniqueness => true** and trigger dirrectly the DB validation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you're trying to test a race condition where the Rails validation doesn't catch the duplicate value, but the database does?

If so, you can just skip the Rails validation in your test with `validate: false`:

```
it 'causes a database index constraint error' do
  Foo.create!(bar: 'baz')
  expect { Foo.create(bar: 'baz', validate: false) }.to raise_error
end
```

If you want to test for a specific error, you should probably also look into the `raise_exception` matcher instead of `raise_error`.